# Not able to make rxjs ajax call iteratively

Tags: javascript, redux, rxjs

I have dispatched an action which has array of userids to be removed . but while doing that in loop i am getting an error saying "You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable" .

```js
const removeUsersEpic = action$ => {
  return action$.ofType(REMOVE_USERS)
    .mergeMap((action) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < action.payload.length; i++) {
        Rx.Observable.ajax({
          headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'test', 'Content-Type': 'application/form-data'},
          method: 'DELETE',
          url: `https://localhost/api/v1/users/${action.payload[i]}`,
          body: {}
        })
        .map((response) => {
          return setUserDeleteCount(action.payload.length)
        }).toPromise()
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
          return setUserDeleteExceptionCount(1)
        })
      }
    }
    )
}
```

The api gets called in loop but after the loop ends i get that error.

Comment: `mergeMap()` needs to return an observable. In your code, it is not returning anything (hence undefined). The return statements in your code are for the inner ajax() stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line with what @kctang already suggested, you may want to try something along these lines

```
const removeUsersEpic = action$ => {
  return action$.ofType(REMOVE_USERS)
    .switchMap((action) => {
      Rx.Observable.from(action.payload).mergeMap(
        payload => Rx.Observable.ajax({
          headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'test', 'Content-Type': 'application/form-data'},
          method: 'DELETE',
          url: `https://localhost/api/v1/users/${payload}`,
          body: {}
        })
    })
}
```

The whole idea is that via `Rx.Observable.from(action.payload)` you create an Observable that emits as many items as the elements in the array `action.payload`.

For each element emitted you create another Observable via `Rx.Observable.ajax`.

You than use `mergeMap` to flatten it and obtain an Observable of responses of Ajax calls.

As soon as you receive an event of type `action$.ofType(REMOVE_USERS)` you want to switch to the new Observable which we have just discussed, i.e. the one you create via `Rx.Observable.from(action.payload).mergeMap(...)`.

Eventually you manage the result of you operations when you subscribe to the Observable you have created via all these transformations

```
removeUsersEpic.subscribe(
  data => console.log('Delete done - response', data),
  err => console.error(err),
  () => setUserDeleteCount(action.payload.length)
)
```

This is just to give you an idea about a way to combine Observables which should help you get what you want. You may want to read [this article](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/rxjs-and-node-8f4e0acebc7c) to have some more details about how to combine Observables using `from` `switchMap` and `mergeMap`.

Comment: Thanks @picci. If i do it via .from then can u help me with triggering an action after the observable stops emitting data. Like in this example , Rx.Observable.from(action.payload) this obsetrvable will stops emitting after there is no item in payload , after that i want to trigger some action . where should i write that

Comment: When an Observable completes, then the function provided as third parameter of `subscribe` (if any) is executed. This is `() => setUserDeleteCount(action.payload.length)`  in the above example